# Estimation of noise parameters from data

Tags: r, linear-regression, noise, non-linear-regression

I'm interested in extracting noise parameters from (x, y) data, where x are known input values, y are the corresponding signals, and I typically know quite well the functional form of the noise-generating processes.

```
###
library(MASS)
n <- 100000
x <- runif(n, min = 50, max = 1000)
y1 <- rnorm(n, 0, 5) + rnegbin(x / 4, theta = 100)
plot(x[1:100000*100], y1[1:100000*100]) #plot every 1ooth datapoint only, for speed
y2 <- x / 7.5 + rnorm(n, 50, 2) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.1 * x / 7.5)
plot(x[1:100000*100], y2[1:100000*100])
y3 <- x + rnorm(n, 0, 5) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.1 * x)
plot(x[1:100000*100], y3[1:100000*100])
y4 <- rnorm(n, 0, 5) + (rnegbin((x + rnorm(n, 0, 5)), theta = 100)) / 2
plot(x[1:100000*100], y4[1:100000*100])
###
```

In the (x, y1) example, the y data are (noisy) counts generated according to a negative binomial  model (theta = 100) plus some constant (homoskedastic) gaussian noise (with avg = 0, stdev = 5) from the input values x.  Also, there is a step somewhere in the process before the generation of the counts that scales down the signal by a factor of 4.

In the (x, y2) example, the signals are generated by a different kind of process where the response factor is 1 / 7.5 so y values are first of all scaled down by that factor, then constant gaussian background noise (avg = 50, stdev = 2), plus more gaussian noise that is proportional to the y (= x / 7.5) is added.

I suppose my main question is: Is there a function or functions that take (x, y) data, as well as user-specified noise model as inputs and spits out the best estimates for, in the case of example y1, the four parameters: theta, constant noise avg, constant noise stdev, and scaling factor?

As a simplification, as in example (x, y3), I may be able to scale the signals manually before the fitting so the signals are (on average) directly proportional to the input, and the algorithm should not consider any scaling factors but assume that on avarage, y is directly proportion to x (slope = 1), eliminating this parameter from consideration, and thus simplifying the fitting process.

There is even more complicated example (x, y4).  Here, the signals are produced by a complex process, with the signal is initially proportional to x (no scaling), constant gaussian noise is added (avg = 0, stdev = 5), then noisy counts are generated from that already noisy input, signals are divided by 2, and then more constant gaussian noise (avg = 0, stdev = 5) is added to top it off.

All these seem like a doable things in data processing oriented R, but I haven't been able to find suitable solution.  Still, I am not very experienced programmer in general (and R specifically), and I don't have any experience in developing algorithms, so my preceptions may be totally off, in that case my apologies.

The noise levels and exact models presented in these toy examples may not be realistic, but I'm just trying to illustrate that I'd like to find a way to model somewhat complex and user-specified multi-parameter noise scenarios.  In lot of cases, I know to high accuracy what kind of processes generated the real-world data of interest so that is not a problem, I can write down the function.  The bottleneck is to know what are the appropriate R function(s)/packages to use (and something like this is available in R) and how to use them correctly so I can extract the parameters (which are my main interest) that characterize these processes.

In case there are no general solutions that would cover lot of ground, I'm of course interested in algorithms and functions that specialize in just one type of data as well (e.g., just linear regression).  Finally, if fitting complex noise models is not an option, I'd be also interested in starting with something simpler, like just fitting negative binomial alone, in some cases other noise sources may be negligible so it may just do.  Like this one

```
y5 <- rnegbin(x, theta = 100)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just an aside, and `n <- 100000` line at the top of your script and using `n` rather than 100000  would make your code more readable and adaptable.

Comment: As for your actual question, it seems like a statistics question rather than an programming question. Most of it boils down to "what model is appropriate". There are standard approaches for modeling, e.g., negative binomial data. And if you have a hypothesized functional form you can model most things... Anyway, I'd suggest asking on stats.stackexchange.com rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Gregor, edited the post.Also, I felt that this is R, rather than statistics question, since I know the models.  Right now, I'm looking for a package or function in R that could do the job.  Nevertheless, will post there if there are no nibbles here in few days. Thank you again.

Comment: Package/function recommendations are actually explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you really know the model, then in many cases you can transform the equation into a likelihood and use an optimizer like `optim` to get the MLE. And maybe it would be useful to know "in cases X and Y, use `glm` with these parameters, in case Z, you can transform it to a simpler case, ..." which seems like a stats answer.

Comment: Sorry, will post to stats.stackexchange.com.